# Let $P(z)=az^2+bz+c$, where $a,b,c$ are complex numbers. Prove that $a=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Question: Let $P(z)=az^2+bz+c$, where $a,b,c$ are complex numbers.
>
> (a) If $P(z)$ is real for all real numbers $z$, show that $a,b,c$ are real numbers.
>
> (b) In addition to $(a)$ above, assume that $P(z)$ is not real whenever $z$ is not real. Show that $a=0$.

My approach: Given that $P(z)\in\mathbb{R}$, whenever $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

This implies that $P(0)=c\in\mathbb{R}$.

This also implies that $P(1)=a+b+c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $P(-1)=a-b+c\in\mathbb{R}$, which implies that $P(1)+P(-1)=2(a+c)\in\mathbb{R}\implies a+c\in\mathbb{R}\implies a\in\mathbb{R}.$

Again we have $P(1)-P(-1)=2b\in\mathbb{R}\implies b\in\mathbb{R}.$

Therefore, $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence we are done with part $(a)$ of the problem.

For the $(b)$ part I was trying to prove that $a=0$ by substituting $z=i$ and $z=-i$ in the given identity. But, couldn't get anything significant out of it.

Hints please.

Comment: You can also look at the equation $P(z)=r$, where $r\in\mathbb R$, assuming $a\ne 0$. From this you can see that $z$ will be non-real for some $r$. Think about the discriminant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\ne0$, $P$ is a quadratic $\in\Bbb R[X]$, so its roots are two (possibly equal) reals or a complex conjugate pair, but (b) precludes the latter. Let $p,q$ be the roots of $P(z)$. So write $P(z)=a(z-p)(z-q)$. But for $t\in\Bbb R$ and $t\neq 0$,$$P((p+q)/2+ti)=-a((p-q)^2/4+t^2).$$